# How to output C++ range-v3 to ostringstream?

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

This range-v3 example doesn't compile with Visual C++ version 15.9:

```
auto letters = ranges::view::iota('a','g');
std::ostringstream out;
out << letters;
```

Is this by design? What is the way to output ranges to `ostringstream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>

int main() {
    auto letters = ranges::view::iota('a','g');
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << letters;
    std::cout << out.str();
}
```

works for me with VS 2017 15.9.3 and range-v3 installed by vcpkg. It outputs `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

Comment: I just upgraded to 15.9.3 and I had range-v3 also installed with vcpkg, but it still doesn't compile: `error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'Stream &'`

Comment: I tried again on a different PC and this time it works. Maybe one of the recent pull requests changed something. Thanks for checking it out.